# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.smartbear.soapui:soapui:[unknown-version]

Tags: maven, soapui

I am trying to create simple MAVEN project which can execute SOAPUI testcases.

Am trying to use the pom.xml mentioned in the SOAPUI website. below is the link:

http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui/5.2.1/

in POM.xml i am getting the following exception:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.smartbear.soapui:soapui:[unknown-version]: Failure to find com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-project:pom:
 5.2.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has 
 elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

As the error message says i think it couldn't found the parent repository.

Comment: You are using somewhere in your pom files a wrong dependency etc. without a version: `com.smartbear.soapui:soapui:[unknown-version]` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for the reply. I added the version for that. Still same issue

Comment: Delete the folder in your local repository `$HOME/.m2/repository/com/smartbear/soapui` and rebuilt...

Comment: Still same isuue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependency you're looking for is in http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/ maven repository, but is not in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ (at least right now, maybe in the futur will be added to the other repo).

The error you're showing is pretty clear in this sense:

> ... Failure to find com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-project:pom:5.2.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 ...

To solve your problem you've to add the smartbear repository in your `POM.xml` or in your maven settings in order to solve the required dependencies. For example to add in your `POM.xml` simply use the `<repositories>` node as follows:

```
<project>
...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>smartbear</id>
      <name>smartbear repository</name>
      <url>http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
...
```

You can see more info about configuring extra maven repositories [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html).